# Intelli Idea usage - How to have quicker launch and lesser memory footprint?

Tags: intellij-idea

I am trying to move from eclipse to intellij idea. I am trying out various dev plugins cases for intellij idea - `android, clojure, scala, python, javascript, java, gwt, dart, jboss, spring` etc as I am keen to learn different aspects of programming*.

The start time increases as more plugins are installed (as mentioned by intellij wiki). How to have quicker launch and lesser memory footprint when using intellij for learning across different programming environment?

I am trying to find out how developers use intellij idea when working with multiple language environment.

**Option 1)** Do we have different intellij installations to work with different language environments i.e in the above scenario have 5-6 different intellij installations with only appropriate plugins installed only. ( **Dumb way** )

**Option 2)** Does intellij idea provide a mechanism to turn off different plugins within a single installation? ( **Smarter Way** )

Comment: See http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-6712 and http://devnet.jetbrains.com/docs/DOC-192. There is not so much difference whether you have all the plug-ins enabled or only some of them. So just keep all you need enabled. Memory is the cheapest resource after all.

Comment: Unfortunately, being stuck in low end memory environment is a reality so often faced by developers. I am trying to find optimal way to use intellij idea when changing hardware is not an option.

Comment: You can limit maximum heap in the `.vmoptions` file, see other suggestions from the links above.

Comment: +1. Going through your links. It looks like i might go with option 1. Do post your links as answer :) . I willupvote it as the tips shared in the articles are helpful.